# Checking Spelling of Word using HashTable

Tags: java, string, hashtable, collision

I have an array of words being inserted into a HashTable.
Then a function that will check if the word that the user typed in is spelled correctly.
My problem is that the spellchecker function only works if i initiate the word, but not if the user inputs the word(even though is spelled correctly).
Program is set up in a way that collisions do not occur, but if you have a suggestion on how to handle them please let me know.

```
public class hashExample {

    String[] myArray = new String[31];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] words = { "Achieve", "Across", "Apparently", "Admin", 
                "Amazing", "Argument", "Assasination", "Accommodate" };

        hashExample theFunc = new hashExample();

        theFunc.hashFunction(words, theFunc.myArray);

        System.out.println("Enter a word to check for spelling...");

        String Word = input.nextLine();
        //Works only if I initiate Word.
        //String Word = "Accommodate";

        theFunc.findKey(Word);
    }

    public void hashFunction(String[] stringsForArray, String[] myArray) {

        for (int n = 0; n < stringsForArray.length; n++) {

            String newElementVal = stringsForArray[n];

            // Using ASCII values of the first four letters of each word.
            int arrayIndex = ((int)newElementVal.charAt(0) + (int)newElementVal.charAt(1)
            + (int)newElementVal.charAt(2)+ (int)newElementVal.charAt(3)) % 31;

            myArray[arrayIndex] = newElementVal;
        }
    }

    public void findKey(String key) {

        int indexHash = ((int)key.charAt(0) + (int)key.charAt(1) + (int)key.charAt(2)
        + (int)key.charAt(3)) % 31;

        String wordSearch = myArray[indexHash];

        if (key == wordSearch){
                System.out.println("Word is spelled correctly!");
            } else{
                System.out.println("Sorry word is not spelled correctly");
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change **key == wordSearch** to **key.equals(wordSearch)** then it will start working with inputs.

Because Strings are objects and if you want to compare two strings, use the .equals method to compare them instead of ==.

```
if (key.equals(wordSearch)) {
    System.out.println("Word is spelled correctly!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry word is not spelled correctly");
}
```